# One of Angular Route is not working in Angular Prod Build

Tags: angular

We have an application where navigation to a purticular route is working as expected in dev serve. But when I build and deploy to prod it is not working as expected and the browser is getting stuck and not able to close or change anything. It is going into hung mode.

I also kept console.logs in the ngOnInit code function calls they are executing fine but browser is hung.

Below is my component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, NgForm, NgModel } from '@angular/forms';
import { SelectionModel } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatCheckboxChange, MatPaginator, MatSort } from '@angular/material';
import { select } from '@angular-redux/store';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { IReportMasters, ITestCode, ICandidateCredentials } from '../api/reports.interface';
import { IRequirementCode } from 'src/app/registration/api/registration.interface';
import { ReportsService } from '../api/reports.service';
import { trigger, transition, useAnimation } from '@angular/animations';
import { bounce } from 'ng-animate';
import { SnackbarService } from 'src/app/material/snackbar.service';
import { MatProgressButtonOptions } from 'mat-progress-buttons';
import { GlobalMessages } from 'src/app/globals/global.messages';
import globalConst from 'src/app/globals/global.const';
import { GlobalService } from 'src/app/services/global.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cadidate-credentials',
  templateUrl: './cadidate-credentials.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cadidate-credentials.component.scss'],
  animations: [trigger('bounce', [transition('* => *', useAnimation(bounce))])]
})
export class CadidateCredentialsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('ccForm', { static: false }) ccForm: NgForm;
  bounce: any;
  today = new Date();
  birthdayMax = globalConst.birthdayMax;
  @select(['reports', 'masters']) masters$: Observable<IReportMasters>;
  @select(['reports', 'reqCodeYear']) reqCodeYear$: Observable<IReportMasters>;
  @select(['reports', 'candidateCredentials', 'masters', 'reqCodes']) reqCodes$: Observable<
    IRequirementCode[]
  >;
  @select(['reports', 'candidateCredentials', 'candidates']) candidates$: Observable<
    ICandidateCredentials[]
  >;
  @select(['reports', 'candidateCredentials', 'masters', 'tests']) tests$: Observable<ITestCode[]>;
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<ICandidateCredentials> = new MatTableDataSource([]);
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['Candidate_Name', 'Login_user_Id', 'Password', 'isActive'];
  private paginator: MatPaginator;
  private sort: MatSort;
  searching: boolean;
  subs: Subscription[] = [];
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) set matSort(ms: MatSort) {
    this.sort = ms;
    this.setDataSourceAttributes();
  }

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: false }) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
    this.paginator = mp;
    this.setDataSourceAttributes();
  }
  @ViewChild('reqCodeV', { static: false }) reqCodeV: NgModel;
  selection = new SelectionModel<ICandidateCredentials>(true, []);
  formGroup: FormGroup;
  locations = [];
  years = [];
  months = [];
  submitting: boolean;
  // candidatesToActivate: ICandidateCredentials[] = [];

  constructor(
    private _reportsService: ReportsService,
    private _globalService: GlobalService,
    private _snackbarService: SnackbarService // private dispatcher: Dispatcher
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setUpLoadingReset();
    this.loadCandidates();
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subs.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());
  }
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log('TCL: ngAfterViewInit');
    this.ccForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      this.searching = false;
    });
  }
  setUpLoadingReset() {
    console.log('TCL: setUpLoadingReset -> setUpLoadingReset');
    this.subs[this.subs.length] = this._globalService.globalLoadingReset$.subscribe(state => {
      console.log('TCL: ngOnInit -> state', state);
      this.searching = false;
      this.submitting = false;
    });
  }
  loadCandidates() {
    console.log('TCL: loadCandidates -> loadCandidates');
    this.subs[this.subs.length] = this.candidates$.subscribe(data => {
      console.log('TCL: loadCandidates -> this.candidates$.subscribe => data', data);
      this.searching = false;
      if (data.length) {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<ICandidateCredentials>(data);
        this.selection = new SelectionModel<ICandidateCredentials>(
          true,
          this.dataSource.data.filter(item => item.isActive)
        );
      }
    });
  }
  /** Whether the number of selected elements matches the total number of rows. */
  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
  }

  /** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection. */
  masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected()
      ? this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => {
          if (!row.isActive) {
            this.selection.toggle(row);
          }
        })
      : this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
  }

  /** The label for the checkbox on the passed row */
  checkboxLabel(row?: ICandidateCredentials): string {
    if (!row) {
      return `${this.isAllSelected() ? 'select' : 'deselect'} all`;
    }
    return `${this.selection.isSelected(row) ? 'deselect' : 'select'} row ${row.Candidate_Name}`;
  }

  reqCodeYearChanged(year, dependentControls: NgModel[]) {
    if (year) {
      this._reportsService.getReqCodesByYear(year);
    }
    dependentControls.forEach(control => control.reset());
  }

  reqCodeChanged(reqcode, dependentControls: NgModel[]) {
    this._reportsService.getTestByReqCode(reqcode);
    dependentControls.forEach(control => control.reset());
  }
  searchCandidateCredentials(ccForm: NgForm) {
    if (ccForm.valid) {
      this.searching = true;
      let sub: Subscription = this._reportsService.getCandidateCredentials(ccForm.value);
    }
  }
  resetForm(ccForm: NgForm) {
    ccForm.resetForm();
    ccForm.controls.IsRetake.setValue(false);
  }
  changedSelection(event: MatCheckboxChange, row: ICandidateCredentials) {
    event ? this.selection.toggle(row) : null;
  }
  setDataSourceAttributes() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
  activateSelected(test) {
    if (this.countToActivate) {
      let candidates = this.selection.selected
        .filter(item => {
          return !item.isActive;
        })
        .map(item => {
          item.isActive = true;
          return item;
        });
      this.submitting = true;
      this.subs[this.subs.length] = this._reportsService
        .saveCandidateCredentials(candidates, test)
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            this.submitting = false;
            this._snackbarService.success(`Activated ${candidates.length} candidate(s).`);
          },
          err => {
            this._snackbarService.error(GlobalMessages.Reports.CANDIDATE_ACTIVATE_ERROR);
            this.submitting = false;
            candidates.forEach(item => {
              item.isActive = false;
            });
          }
        );
    } else {
      this._snackbarService.info('Please select atlease one candidate to activate.');
    }
  }
  get countToActivate() {
    return this.selection.selected.filter(item => {
      return !item.isActive;
    }).length;
  }

  get activateButtonOptions(): MatProgressButtonOptions {
    return {
      active: this.submitting,
      text: this.submitting ? 'Saving Data...' : 'Activate',
      buttonColor: 'accent',
      barColor: 'primary',
      raised: true,
      stroked: false,
      mode: 'indeterminate',
      value: 0,
      disabled: false,
      fullWidth: false,
      buttonIcon: {
        fontIcon: 'save'
      }
    };
  }
  get searchButtonOptions(): MatProgressButtonOptions {
    return {
      active: this.searching,
      text: this.searching ? 'Searching ...' : 'Search',
      buttonColor: 'primary',
      barColor: 'accent',
      raised: true,
      stroked: false,
      mode: 'indeterminate',
      value: 0,
      disabled: false,
      fullWidth: false,
      buttonIcon: {
        fontIcon: 'search'
      }
    };
  }
  resetValue(item: NgModel) {
    console.log('TCL: resetValue -> item', item);
    item.reset();
  }
}
```

Update1: Console.log ScreenShot in Prod

[image]

Update2: Expected result is below from dev ng serve
[image: Expected Result in dev mode]

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: Can you show your console?
Maybe spelling error. Try **tslint** in your code before deploy.

Comment: In edge browser it says long running script and prompts me to stop script.

Comment: I don't think it is related to routing. Set debug points in you setUpLoadingReset(). why there is no log for 'console.log('TCL: ngOnInit -> state', state)' Check you network tab, either you are getting response or not

Comment: seems like something to do with animation , can you share the animation snippet you used?

Comment: I used  bounce  from 'ng-animate' for a button  <mat-bar-button
        *ngIf="dataSource.data.length"
        class="float-button"
        [options]="activateButtonOptions"
        (btnClick)="activateSelected(testV.value)"
        [matBadge]="countToActivate"
        matBadgePosition="after"
        [@bounce]="bounce"
        >
      </mat-bar-button>

Comment: Is it working if the code is run normally without the --prod flag?

Comment: Yes ng serve is working as expected

Comment: @YogendraR I used a rx js subject to reset the loading state.  Below is the code in service.                                                                                          
   private globalLoadingReset = new Subject();
  public globalLoadingReset$ = this.globalLoadingReset.asObservable();

Comment: Could you delete all logic from component, try to rebuild it with - - prod flag? It will help clarify    source of the issue. Seems the issue with redux selectors or something like that

Answer (score 0):

It looks suspicious that your component is initialized (calling ngOnInit) but never enters AfterViewInit. So it looks to me as if something in your template or after the OnInit (like ViewChild code, or the animation) was wrong.

In case it would be something with routing causing your page to crash, it would be an endless loop and trying to navigate multiple times, but never really enter the component. To prove that, you can enable the router logging with the enableTracing option:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true })
```

Comment: I did and there is no such infinite redirection happening. I am suspecting some JavaScript is being executed indefinitely and blocking the UI to render couldn't find what it is. I used the mat-bar-button from mat-progress-buttons npm package. Not sure if it is causing issue.

Comment: Ok cool, that is already something good, no routes problem. To locate your real problem better, you can debug deeper into your JavaScript, into all the parts which are called from your templates (also console.logs can provide great help), and if that does not help, throw out piece by piece every suspicious part of your code (and template)